# How do I take the output from STDIN and redirect it into the input of a socket?

Tags: ruby, stdin

Basically, I want to take the output of STDIN and keep it written out to a socket. How would I go about this? Neither Google nor `ri` are of help

Comment: `some_socket.write STDIN.read`? What did you try? And what problems did you encounter?

Comment: STDIN is input to your program, not output.  This makes "output of STDIN" a contradiction.  Can you please edit your question to this up?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker How do I keep it constantly written out?

Comment: @WayneConrad From the program, wouldn't it be seen as an output-only stream?

Comment: A program sees its own stdin as an input-only stream.  I wonder if you are talking about spawning another program and redirecting _it's_ stdin.  If that's the case, you ought to mention it.